# Нет доступа к файлу c#

Tags: c#, файлы

```
 for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
                {

                    var fil2 = File.ReadAllBytes(@listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
                 using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("done.exe", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
                    {

                        fs.Write(fil2, 0, fil2.Length);
                    }

                }
```

Если цикл идет до 2,то все нормально, но стоит циклу идти до 3, как дает ошибку, что не может получить доступ к done.exe т.к он занят другим процессом, можете помочь решить проблему ?

Comment: Вы тележку не к ишаку прицепили, а ишака в тележку положили и спрашиваете, почему не едет?! Цикл `for` нужно внутрь `using (FileStream...)` переместить.

Comment: да, спасибо большое

Comment: @Bulson, почему не как ответ? =)

Comment: @AntonKomyshan не стоит оно того.